# With T extending Record<string, any>, keyof T does not give 'string' as type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to achieve the following:

```js
type MyFormProps<FieldName extends keyof FormShape, FormShape extends Record<string, any>> = {
  id: string;
  value: FormShape[FieldName];
}

const formPropsBuilder = <FieldName extends keyof FormShape, FormShape extends Record<string, any>>(
  name: FieldName,
  form: FormShape,
): MyFormProps<FieldName, FormShape> => {
  return {
    id: name,
    value: form[name],
  }
}
```

But I get an error saying that name is of type `string | number | symbol`.

It's weird since FormShape does extend `Record<string, any>`, so its keys need to be strings.

Is it normal?
If so, is there any way to make it work?

Thanks ;)

Link to the playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiB7ATgWwArMWAzgHngEsIAbAEwDkBDVaCAD2AgDsycoBrCERAMyiRoAygAsqkADQCUqUeLqMWbKACUIAYxRk8OYMkLMA5lKrMQAPnNQAvFADeAKChRCZAFxRd+owG4nUADcqEgBXCA9BWTFIAG0iUkoaCABdPwBfBwdNZl0oXhlMbBwAIRDCcghkGygCYnJqWigGJlZ2Lh5+SLlJaWFohRblNU1kbS8DYyhTC3MACn9mJIi6xNoJf3y0CJluiHWASg84SMLcWoSGvd6o+StrK0dnZAhgEORme39nVw9Fta-AsEwh5NqgYn8UutnBk0kA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think has 3 types of index type `string` | `number` | `symbol` so in order to assign to it, you might have to make `id` having the same type above.

```js
type MyFormProps = {
  id: string | number | symbol;
}
```

Or you can also cast your type as string if you believe the input always is string:

```
const formPropsBuilder = <K extends keyof T, T extends Record<string, any>>(name: K): MyFormProps => {
  return {
    id: name as string,    
  }
}
``
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this bizarre as well.  Here is my workaround:

```
type StringKey<T extends Record<string, any>> = keyof T extends string
  ? keyof T
  : never
```

Now you have `StringKey<Record<string, any>>` extends string.

Comment: You could also do `Extract<T, string>`

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for the additional generic type? I would simplify it to:

```
type MyFormProps = {
  id: string;
}

const formPropsBuilder = <FieldName extends keyof Record<string, any>>(name: FieldName): MyFormProps => {
  return {
    id: name,
  }
}
```

The error disappears with this simplification.

Comment: If `FieldName extends keyof Record<string, any>` then `FieldName` ***is*** `string` (with no further constraints). Why use generics at all?

Comment: Aaah sorry, this is a good point: my example is incomplete. `FieldName extends FormShape`, and `FormShape extends Record<string, any>`, but might be a well-defined dictionary. I oversimplified it.

Comment: I edited my post to give more meaning to the example.