# How can I narrow the typing of `T extends {}` to require `keyof T` to always be sting?

Tags: typescript

I currently have this mapping type, and it works great in a lot of situations:

```js
type WithKeyPrefix<P extends string, T extends {}> = {
  [K in Extract<keyof T, string> as `${P}/${K}`]: T[K];
};
```

However, I can't get it to reject objects which contain non-string keys. I've tried a couple different solutions so far, but nothing that works as I'd like it to:

```js
type WithKeyPrefix<P extends string, T extends {}> = {
  [K in Extract<keyof T, string> as `${P}/${K}`]: T[K];
} & {
  [K in Exclude<keyof T, string>]: never;
};
```

```js
type WithKeyPrefix<P extends string, T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
  [K in Extract<keyof T, string> as `${P}/${K}`]: T[K];
};
```

The first makes no apparent difference. The second produces this error when `T` is an interface with limited keys:

```
TS2344: Type 'Foo' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<string, unknown>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'Foo'.
```

Is there a way to constrain the type of `T` in the way I want?

---

**Bonus question:** Why is `Extract<keyof T, string>` needed even when `T` is constrained as `Record<string, unknown>`?

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63721756/1813169) already, but the solutions there are effectively workarounds which are perfectly valid in the context of that question, but cannot work in my situation; hence the new question.

Answer (score 1):

To reject objects with non-string properties you may rewrite your type as:

```ts
type WithKeyPrefix<
    P extends string,
    T extends object & (keyof T extends string ? {} : "Must have only string keys"),
> = {
    [K in Extract<keyof T, string> as `${P}/${K}`]: T[K];
};
```

Credits for string only keys constraint go to this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52660867/3388225)

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXRXLm)

As for `Extract<keyof T, string>` it's required because something that extends `Record<string, any>` is not [guaranteed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33440#issuecomment-531654080) to have only `string` keys.